# Windows Update consumes all available internet bandwidth

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I found that Windows 10 totally consumes all the available internet bandwidth while updating, so much so that other computers within the LAN cannot surf the internet until the update finishes (ISP plan is 10Mbit/s).

Windows Update establishes multiple connections to the Update servers (more than 20), maximizing the download speed - but why? This is a background service that should not distract a user from his work, and instead almost blocks the internet to all users that share the same internet connection.

Also, I see that the "Delivery optimization" can optimize update downloads by downloading once and spreading updates over LAN; I have one computer receiving all updates, but the second still downloads updates from internet.

ADD: What is correct way to limit used bandwidth? I know there is bandwidth limit  settings, as percents where minimum is 5%. But is it work correct if LAN is 1GB/s, but ISP plan is 10 MB/s?

Comment: Make sure Delivery Optimization is ON but only for PCs on your LAN not over the Internet (second setting)

Comment: Also, 10 Mbits/sec download is not very fast for that many users which is why you are seeing the slowness

Comment: Implementing QoS on the router should also help, as would setting a time under the Windows Update Settings page to a time when you're not using the PC (such as at night)

Comment: Your question of "Why?" is opinion based and is off topic.